# Calling Webservice from HLR

Tags: web-services

I tried to search on Google but didn't get any answer. Just few hints I got. My requirement is that on first time SIM activation I want to receive a trigger on my webservice, which can send a SMS to that SIM card. So is it possible to configure a URL using TCP/IP protocol in HLR. I know on SMSC we can configure this, and that is working fine for me.